# Visual MySQL compare tool for Mac

Tags: mac, data-synchronization, mysql

Is there any Mac app that can visually compare data like SQLyog's Visual Data Compare?

One where you can literally select the rows to copy over and which not?

Any recommendations appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Toad for Mac](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-mac-edition/) has data and schema compare features. You can download for free in the link provided.

**UPDATE**: In the latest version (1.2.1), does not have data and schema compare features.

Comment: Is there a **Mac** version of this? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Sure. We are on a Mac forum, isn't it?

Comment: I'm looking at that link and it says only Windows. Either I'm blind or the link is wrong...!?

Comment: Sorry I wrote a bad link. Updated.

Comment: Cool! Installing now, might be what I was looking for as well. BTW, the direct link to the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/toad/id747961939?l=en&mt=12

Comment: Can it do visual comparison like SQLyog does?

Comment: I've downloaded Toad, and I can't find any comparison features. Do you mind elaborating on how to activate it?

Comment: I use some time ago an had it. I'm trying now, and as you told does not have it. Toad for Mac is under an early stage of development and when I tried interface sucks but have lots of functionalities, now is just the opposite, the interface is fine, but the functionality is really poor. Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: It only works for Oracle databases

Answer (score 0):

After trying 3 different tools, the only that actually worked flawlessly was MySQL Workbench by Oracle: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/